# Does the space has to be Hausdorff for Lusin's theorem to make sense?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Our teacher gave us a proof of Lusin's Theorem, in which he used "facts" like compact sets are closed, intersection of compact sets are compact etc, but in the statement of the theorem it isn't explicitly mentioned that we are working in a Hausdorff space, and as I know this "facts" are not generally true, expect when we are working in such a space. Can someone clarify this for me, should the Hausdorff space be mentioned in the theorem?!!!

Comment: Lusin's theorem is true for measurable functions on Radon measure spaces mapping to a second-countable space. A Radon measure space is Hausdorff by definition. Perhaps you could provide the exact statement of the theorem as it was covered in the lecture?

Comment: It was actually just the classical statement as shown in the Wikipedia link that  Henno Brandsma mentioned below, but in class, we didn't mention the general form, nor did we define Radon measures before!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it must be Hausdorff. The general theorem is stated [here, e.g.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lusin%27s_theorem), where $f$ is a map between a [Radon measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radon_measure) space $(X,\Sigma,\mu)$ and a second countable space $Y$. A Radon measure space is indeed Hausdorff, see the link.